# schedules[0].timings[0].startTime must be a `string` type, but the final value was: `null` - getting this value when field remains empty

Tags: reactjs, forms, yup

const validationSchema = () => {

```
return Yup.lazy(values => {
    return Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string().required("This field is required"),
        streetAddress: Yup.string().required("This field is required"),
        city: Yup.string().required("This field is required"),
        state: Yup.string().required("This field is required"),
        zipCode: Yup.string().required("This field is required"),
        country: Yup.string().required("This field is required"),
        phone: Yup.string().required("This field is required"),
        //   consultingCharge: Yup.string().required("This field is required"),
        schedules: Yup.array().of(
            Yup.object().shape({
                available: Yup.boolean(),
                timings: Yup.array().of(
                    Yup.object().shape({
                        startTime: Yup
                            .string()
                            .when('available', {
                                is: true,
                                then: Yup.string().required('Field is required'),
                                otherwise: Yup.string()
                            }),

                        endTime: Yup
                            .string()
                            .when('available', {
                                is: true,
                                then: Yup.string().required('Field is required'),
                                otherwise: Yup.string()
                            })
                            .test("",  "End time must be after Start time" ,  function(values){
                                return this.parent.startTime < values;
                            }),

                    })
                )
            })
        )
    })
})
```

}

Facing the below error:
schedules[0].timings[0].endTime must be a `string` type, but the final value was: `null`. If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`

When leave the field blank for start time and end time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is related to the schema, I can imagine you use it in combination with formik or some other form library? It looks like your state that is getting validated against that schema is providing a `null` value for the endTime property. Can you verify it's not an issue with the state object itself? Could it be that you have an input field which is empty and the onChange handler is setting the value from the state to `null` instead of `""`? :)